# How to serve media files on Django production environment?

Tags: python, django

In me settings.py file :-

```
DEBUG = False
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In my urls.py file:-

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I am uploading the profile image then it is uploading to specified folder. but when i am visiting the user profile url then i am getting error like this in terminal

```
"GET /media/profile_images/a_34.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 103
```

a_34.png is present in /media/profile_images/

then why it is not showing on browser and i am getting 404 error?

Comment: Because the Django folks insist that in production you'd configure your webserver to point to that static media root instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what should i do now?

Answer (score 16):

Django is not made to serve media file in production environment. You must configure the `STATIC_ROOT` settings and alias webserver to directly serve.

For example

If you are using apache web server in production, add the below to your virtualhost configuration

```
Alias /media/ /path/to/media_file/

<Directory /path/to/media_file/>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you use Nginx you would have to use something like

```
location /media {
    alias /path/to/media/file; # Change to your own media directory here.
    access_log off;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also serve static files from AWS S3 or other cloud servers using [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: This may be a stupid question but how do I know if I am using an apache or nginx server?  When I am deploying django, I am using gunicorn.  Do I have to stop using gunicorn then?

Comment: instead of alias `root` worked in my case for Nginx.

Answer (score 8):

Django discourages to serve media files on production from the server. Use cloud services like amazon s3 to server your media files. See this [Django doc serve media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) then give that path in MEDIA_URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use S3 Amazon for static and media files. It will be better.

---

**Problem with S3 Amazon**

Making the S3 bucket appear as part of the file system has terrible performance and fails randomly. When we are copying a lot of files it can take 10, 15, or 20 minutes for the copying to complete making deployments take a long time when they don’t need to. If we send these directly into S3 the same copy command takes about 1 minute to complete.

**Solution**

Subclass S3BotoStorage twice, one class for static files and the other for media files. This allows us to use different buckets and subdirectories for each type. (see: custom_storage.py)

**Update settings**

```
1. AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME  needs to be bucket to hold static files and media files
2. MEDIAFILES_BUCKET
3. MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
4.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
5.STATICFILES_BUCKET
6.STATICFILES_LOCATION
This is the subdirectory under the S3 bucket for the app
7.STATIC_URL
8.STATICFILES_STORAGE
```

---

Create **custom_storage.py** with the contents:

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.conf import settings

@deconstructible
class StaticS3Storage(S3BotoStorage):
   bucket_name = settings.STATICFILES_BUCKET
   location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

@deconstructible
class MediaS3Storage(S3BotoStorage):
   bucket_name = settings.MEDIAFILES_BUCKET
   location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

---

Sample **settings.py.tmpl** for updates settings (as mentioned above) based on my stack.json

```
MEDIAFILES_BUCKET = '<%= @node["apps_data"]["aws"]["buckets"]["bucket-name"] %>'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'folder_name_for_media_files_in_bucket'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storage.MediaS3Storage'

# If we're not using our S3 backend storage we need to serve the media files via path
   if DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE == "custom_storage.MediaS3Storage":
       MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/%s/' %      (MEDIAFILES_BUCKET, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
   else:
       MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

   STATICFILES_BUCKET = '<%= @node["apps_data"]["aws"]["buckets"]["bucket-name"] %>'
   STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'folder_name_for_static_files_in_bucket'
   STATICFILES_STORAGE = '<%= @node["deploy_data"]["project_name"]["django_static_files_storage"] %>'

# If we're not using our S3 backend storage we need to serve the static files via path
   if STATICFILES_STORAGE == "custom_storage.StaticS3Storage":
       STATIC_URL = 'https://%s.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/%s/' % (STATICFILES_BUCKET, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
   else:
       STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

---

### load static from staticfiles Django Template Tag

Change all uses of **{% load static %}** in templates to **{% load static from staticfiles %}**

The “static” from static files can make use of different back ends for files, including an S3 back end or local file back end. Using “load static” uses the Django template tags library which doesn’t handle different back ends.

Use this in the templates when including a static file and after including “static from staticfiles”:
{% static “path/to/the/file.ext” %}
This will figure out the full path to the file or if it’s in S3 it will insert a full URL to the file.

**Example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% load static from staticfiles %}{% static "css/style.css" %}”>
```

**Useful info**

“django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage” is the default Django static files backend

**References**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Answer (score 3):

For nginx it works for me with the following configuration lines:

```
location /media {
    alias /home/ubuntu/speedy-net/media; # Change to your own media directory here.
    access_log off;
}
```

Also see [my related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225925/is-it-a-good-practice-to-save-media-files-on-the-same-server-in-django) on Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a server to serve static content on production. When only Debug is True, static content is served by Django. So you need to

1) Setup a server

2) Point server media path to STATIC_ROOT directory

3) Run collectstatic command of django to collect all the static files to STATIC_ROOT.
Please refer

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1):

The following method worked for me:

I added the following configuration in Apache config file:

```
alias /media/ /path/to/media/
<Directory /alchemus/django/WebForm/media>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`settings.py` file contained the following settings for MEDIA:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Make sure you have the following settings in `urls.py`:

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The above setting is to make sure that django server only serves media files during development, serving media files in production should be handled by Apache server.

References: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
       .........

       .........

    
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but the logic is that django serves media files when it's in production mode. That means when `debug` is `True` but when `debug` is set to `False` means in production mode you will need to specify the media URL too in your 1urls_pattern`.

I got it fixed with:

```
# import serve and repath
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import path, include,re_path
```

and then added:

```
re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',serve,{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

to my `urls_patterns`.