# Django Image Not found using template tags

Tags: python, django

I'm in trouble for many days now and all solutions given didn't helped me yet.
The image profile I want to show doesn't appear if I use the template variable {{ userprofile.photo.url}} (the result is the Alt text) but it does work when I put the path to the image like this : /dashboard/media/dashboard/photo/profils/user.png.

I've tried to debug, it seems the url is good but the result given is this :

```
[27/Nov/2017 13:55:07] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 44757
Not Found: /media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png
[27/Nov/2017 13:55:07] "GET /media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2295
```

Here the files of the project :

Structure of the project :

```
project_dir/
 dash-app/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
 dashboard/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    app.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    ...
  templates/
    dashboard/
       index.html
       ...
  static/
    dashboard/
      images/
         logo9.png
         ...
  media/
    dashboard/
      photos/
        profils/
           user.png
           ...
```

#### On the urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from dashboard import models
from dashboard import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

#### On the settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "static")

#dashboard/media/
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media", "dashboard")
```

#### On the models.py :

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
    # Physical file location ROOT
    location='{0}/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
    # Url for file
    base_url='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
)

def image_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/dashboard/picture/<filename>
    return 'photos/profils/{0}'.format(filename)

def logo_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/dashboard/picture/<filename>
    return 'photos/logos/{0}'.format(filename)

...

   # Photos
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
                              upload_to=image_directory_path, 
                              storage=image_storage)

    # Logo de l'activité
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, 
                              upload_to=logo_directory_path, 
                              storage=image_storage)
```

#### On the views.py :

```
def index(request):
    connected = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print(connected.photo.url)
    context={
        'userprofile':connected,
    }    
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

#### On the index.html :

```
 <!-- menu profile quick info -->
  <div class="profile clearfix">
    <div class="profile_pic">

    {% if userprofile.photo %}
        <img src="{{ userprofile.photo.url }}" alt="User" class="img-circle profile_img">
    {% else %}
        <img src="media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="profile_info">
      <span>Bienvenu,</span>
      <h2>{{ userprofile }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /menu profile quick info -->
```

I'm using python 3 and Django 1.11.5
Thank tou for your help !

> **EDIT :** I've opened the application on a private navigation to reload and see if there was someting on cache and know I see that nothing works, neither : `{{ userprofile.photo.url|slice:"1:" }}` or `media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png` . Is ther something to reload the >media's file links to the project or something like that. Because If add the image manualy to the folder or if I upload it via Django Admin Interface, is there some difference ?
>
> **SOLVED :** I changed these lines :
>   `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media", "dashboard")` to  `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media")`
>
> `image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
>           # Physical file location ROOT
>           location='{0}/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
>           # Url for file
>           base_url='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
>       )`
>
> to
>
> `image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
>           # Physical file location ROOT
>           location='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
>           # Url for file
>           base_url='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
>       )`

Comment: if you just do `<span>{{ userprofile.photo.url }}</span>` what does it show? Is it the exact same link? Maybe there is a duplication of `/` somewhere. Try this out and compare.

Comment: try with `{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ userprofile.photo.url }}`

Comment: and if you are actually trying to learn for production you need to disable `DEBUG=False` in settings.py and for serving static files you need to configure your server/pc where your project running with [apache](https://coderwall.com/p/ooerda/python-django-apache-ubuntu) or nginx

Comment: @N. Ivanov :
Thank you for the Answer.
It shows me the path at the place of the image :
/media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png

So it appears that it's on the right place but doesn't get the image.

Comment: yes but do you notice that on your comment the link starts with a `/` while on your working example it does not have `/`, but rather starts directly with `media`. This might be the problem. I recall that the fix was something with trailing slashes in settings.py. To see if this is the problem you can do try something like: `{{ userptofile.photo.url|slice:"1:" }}` inside your `src=" "`, and see if that will help. What it does, is it just removes that starting `/`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Sanca Kembang : Thank you for the Answer. The URL is already the good one as answered to Ivanov, so it can't be that for me.
I've tryed the commande you said and got this :
Not Found: /media//media/dashboard/photos/profils/

This is because the url is correctely defined in the model.py via image_storage = FileSystemStorage, so adding {{ MEDIA_URL }} will add a /media/ twice.

Comment: @N. Ivanov : I tryed it on the span and gives as you said the path within the first '/', but on src it doesn't show up the image.
When I do inspect on the browser I get : `src(unknown)` !

Comment: @Gahan : Thank you for your attention. I'm in developpement mode know so DEBUG is True.

Comment: sorry, then I have no idea. Try and debug it

Comment: @N.Ivanov Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED :

I changed these lines :
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media", "dashboard")`
to
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media")`

```
image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
          # Physical file location ROOT
          location='{0}/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
          # Url for file
          base_url='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
      )
```

to

```
image_storage = FileSystemStorage(
          # Physical file location ROOT
          location='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT),
          # Url for file
          base_url='{0}/dashboard/'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a computed property on model that returns relative URL to media file.

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
...

   @property
   def photo_url(self):
       return '{}{}'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.img)
```

Then use this computed property in template:

```
{% if userprofile.photo %}
    <img 
       src="{{ userprofile.photo_url }}"
       alt="User" 
       class="img-circle profile_img"
    >
{% else %}
```

If you're running in development, you can [register a route in your project urls for media files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
] + static.static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Otherwise, consider uploading media files to a digital asset management system like Amazon S3 or [writing server rules to serve your assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051206/how-to-serve-media-files-on-django-production-evironment).

Comment: Thank you Oluwafemi Sule for your answer.
I understand the proprety you coded but is it so different from what I've done on my model ? As said to N. Ivanov, I get the good path/url.

About the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` they are different in my code. Why does it have to match ? can I have `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + 'dashboard/media/dashboard' and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`? Maybe the problem is here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @HamzDiou About setting `MEDIA_URL` to `MEDIA_ROOT`, that part of my answer is actually misleading. I'll correct that. What is important is constructing a correct asset URL  and handling how assets are served from that URL. To answer your question, MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL don't have to match.

Comment: Ok thank you. So for the construction of a correct asset URL, as I understand, if my image is on the physical directory : `C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\project_dir\dashboard\media\dashboard\photos\profils\user.png`, my `MEDIA_ROOT` will be `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dashboard", "media", "dashboard")` and if `{{ userprofile.photo.url }}` gives `media/dashboard/photos/profils/user.png` can we consider that it's correctely constructed ? And what about handling the files served by the URL because I think that is the matter here.

Comment: Yes, the asset url is correctly constructed. I [replicated your code](https://github.com/osule/djangostein/blob/master/web/home/models.py). Ensure to `cd` to web if you clone and runserver. You can upload a photo at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/photo` and view it at`http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`. 

About handling how files are served from that URL, you can use the `static` urlpattern factory provided in Django for to register a media url pattern _if running in development_.