# how to serve django media files in LiteSpeed webserver

Tags: django, deployment, litespeed, django-media

I deployed a django project on shared host , and my media files did not loaded[product image not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3RUv.png)

what config do i do for fix this issue?

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/site_statics/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn", "static_root")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  "static_cdn","media_root")
# MEDIA_ROOT = '/static_cdn/media_root'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('<lang>/', home_page, name='home'),
path('', home_redirect),
path('<lang>/products/', include('products.urls')),
path('<lang>/', include('agents.urls')),
path('<lang>/', include('information.urls')),
path('<lang>/', include('media_app.urls')),

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Will it shows if you run Django app locally? 

If you browser developer tool, what HTTP status error code shows for those missing images? 404, 403?

Comment: @Eric No,I dont.it Deployed on shared host

Comment: Django is not meant to serve media files in production. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051206/how-to-serve-media-files-on-django-production-environment

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the media context for your virtual host in LSWS settings.

1. In your LSWS management GUI, click Virtual Hosts
2. Click the name of the virtual host you are using (the default is Example)
3. Click the Context tab
4. Click the + in the right hand side of the page to add a new context
5. Select the Type Static
6. Set the URI to `/media/` (trailing slash is necessary as this is a directory)
7. Set the Location to your filesystem media folder location
8. Set Accessible to Yes

You can refer to the static context for an example. It will be set up the same way but with different URI and root.